# Can we get the [status] information on the Related Questions as well the Questions list?

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, on-hold, related-questions

The righthand edge Linked and Related questions are cool, I love them, I hate opening a likely looking post and discovering I can't contribute because it's already [closed] or [on-hold] for whatever reason. In the Questions tab we see this information before we open a question and we're warned that it's read-only, can we get that information on the related questions list as well?

Comment: Related: [Prevent questions closed as “off topic” or “not a real question” from showing up in the “Related” links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100705/prevent-questions-closed-as-off-topic-or-not-a-real-question-from-showing-up) and [Related Questions Include Closed Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14614/related-questions-include-closed-questions). Not going to answer because it feels like a duplicate to the one you just deleted [here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5346/28789) and I don't think it's necessary. You can still contribute to closed

Comment: Okay so can we all as users of a particular exchange access the overarching meta-stackexchange that those answers come from? If so how and where?

Comment: Just head on over to [meta.se]. If you don't have an account there associated with your current one, creating one is a simple click away.

Comment: Thanks I'll use that to back check my meta questions in future.